# AngularJS resource factory always returns empty response

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-resource

Ok, so I think I'm missing something basic here but I couldn't figure it out reading the docs and other examples. I have a resource in a factory like this:

```
loteManager.factory('Lotes', function($resource) {
  return $resource('./api/lotes/:id',{ id:"@id" }, {
     get:  {method:'GET', isArray:true}
   });
});
```

And my controller:

```
loteManager.controller('LoteCtrl',
  function InfoCtrl($scope, $routeParams, Lotes) {
    Lotes.get(function (response){
      console.log(response);
    });
});
```

It works when I define the id manually like this `$resource('./api/lotes/21'` so I think the problem is passing the id to the factory but I already tried adding `params:{id:"@id"}` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the id.

Something like this:

```
loteManager.controller('LoteCtrl',
  function InfoCtrl($scope, $routeParams, Lotes) {
    Lotes.get({id: $routeParams.loteId}, function (response){
      console.log(response);
    });
});
```

...assuming you have a route defined something like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/somepath/:loteId, {
    templateUrl: 'sometemplate.html',
    controller: LoteCtrl
});
```

Per the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource#Usage):

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
  user.abc = true;
  user.$save();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is you are saying there are parameters for your 'get' method (id), but you aren't giving the method 'get' an id when you make your call at Lotes.get(..)

So, I think, your method call should be something along the lines of

```
Lotes.get({id: SOME_Id}, function(response){
    // ...do stuff with response
});
```

I'm not totally sure on that syntax, because personally I prefer the [$q](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) service as it provides much more flexibility, but that is what's going wrong with your code in general, you aren't giving your method the parameter it needs (an id).

Also, remember to utilize your Angular's [$timeout](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.%24timeout) service, as you are making an async call.

Comment: ahh just saw @moderndegree 's post. So I guess my syntax is correct, but still remember the $timeout service, you are going to need it in a second.

Comment: could you expand as to why I have to use the $timeout service? It seems to work fine now without it.

Comment: So $resource is making an async request. Since Javascript is innately sync you need to $timeout the system (for a certain amount of milliseconds) to allow the async request to complete.